# NSData on firebase

Tags: objective-c, firebase

I am trying to get my app connected with firebase but one of the things I need is to be able to save a PDF file to firebase or an NSData object. So using objective c how can I save a NSData object as a value in firebase?

Comment: Have you worked through the [iOS Firebase Quick Start](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/)?  Have you read the guide?  Which step did you have trouble with?  Show us your code.

Comment: Or are you just looking for a pointer to the [`UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData) function?

Comment: According to your docs, Data types that can be set are: NSString, NSNumber, NSDictionary, NSArray. I currently convert the PDF to NSData and I need to save that as a value in firebase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution is to encode your `NSData` as an `NSString` using base 64 encoding:

```
NSString *stringForm = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

and then convert it back later:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:stringForm options:0];
```

iOS 7.0 and OS X 10.9 support these methods.  If you need to support an earlier OS, you can find several base-64 encoding implementations on the web.

#### UPDATE

In Swift:

```
let stringForm = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])

let dataOption = NSData(base64EncodedString: stringForm, options: [])
```

Note that `dataOption` is an `Optional<NSData>`, and is nil if `stringForm` doesn't contain valid base-64-encoded data.